# MC Bedrock Edition: Line 1, Column 2 '}' missing or object member name

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

So I'm trying to mess around with the command blocks in Minecraft Bedrock Edition.
In this I was trying to give a wooden sword a sharpness 32K and a unbreaking 1000 enchantment.
The code I use is:

```
give @p wooden_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:32000},{id:34,lvl:1000}]}
```

The only thing to come out of this is the output: `Line 1, Column 2 '}' missing or object member name`

I read on the internet that this might have something to do with the JSON code and that I should use " " on the objects in the command, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm at a loss and have no idea how to fix this or what exactly causes it.

Anyone willing to help me with this?

Comment: and even in a game made of cubes I still have trouble writing a simple piece of code.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How do you add NBT tags to commands in Minecraft Pocket/Bedrock Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/219480). tl;dr: Not all Java Edition commands work in Bedrock Edition, and giving items with enchantments is one that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Java commands apparently dont work for bedrock as Joseph Sible pointed out.

this concludes this question.